# how to set view controller programmatically for subview in storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

(Designed in storyboard , screenshot below) I have two subviews on my rootviewcontroller's view

[image]

In my code i want to assign a **separate** view controller to each subview. i.e Assign a tableViewController to the TableView.

I tried to do this in awakeFromNib (or ViewDidLoad) method but to no avail. The delegate method in my tableview controller are never called. I think storyboard does the job of loading the subviews here even before the tableviewcontroller i assign can do something.

```
self.myTableViewController = (TodoListViewController *)[[UITableViewController alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.myTableView.delegate = self.myTableViewController;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self.myTableViewController;
self.myTableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;
```

I am not sure if this is allowed when having views like this in storyboard or i am doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I came to this site as I had a similar problem. Actually I am doing the exact same thing: I have a viewcontroller with two subviews (all defined in a storyboard with lots of constraints).

in the containerviewcontroller in viewDidLoad I am doing the same calls as you do (but I defined the view first):

```
self.myTableViewController = (TodoListViewController *)[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.myTableViewController.tableView = self.myTableView;
self.myTableView.delegate = self.myTableViewController;
self.myTableView.dataSource = self.myTableViewController;
```

That works for me (I guess, here is your problem: You don't have a navigation controller around it.... and be sure that the outlets of your tableview are really connected in the storyboard.).

But the real problem comes after the correct wiring. If you tab into a cell, you probably want to give some cellID to the nextView. As you have defined your tableviewcontroller manually, only your delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath gets called, but not the prepareForSegue.

I have played around with instantiating the viewcontroller from the storyboard

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"aStoryboard" bundle:nil];
self.myTableViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myTableViewID"];
```

but the segue did not get called. calling it directly (performSegueWithIdentifier:...) did not work as this tableviewcontroller is not managed by a navigation controller.

For me it ended up that the prepareForSegue method gets called in the containerViewController which can delegate the calls to its subviewcontrollers.

**EDIT: Actually the real solution is DON'T.** There is a "Container View" object which can be added to a view and defines a region of a view controller that can include a child view controller. This is what I really wanted to do.

Comment: +1 for the "container view" part. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try again with your viewDidLoad method, that is the simplest answer. If the method is not loading you may have to look into the other things inside you method because if the application is large as they often are using storyboards you may have conflicting methods.

I would also look at this:
http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx

It shows the most common accidents people make when using any storyboard function programatically

Hope that helps!

Comment: good point , but the app is pretty simple at the moment and does not have a lot of code to overlap as you have pointed out. so trying again in ViewDidLoad is not much of help at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to write yourself a custom container controller, e.g. similar to UISplitViewController.  Here's apple's brief docs on doing this in the [UIViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81).  You could for example instantiate the children controllers programmatically in your container controller's `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` methods.  I don't think you can get IB to instantiate the children for you, though, in the same way you can wire up say a tab bar or navigation controller's relationships to their children.  (If there is a way, I'd like to know!)

Answer (score -1):

It's typically easiest to set your classes and delegates all in the storyboard (as shown in numerous totorials including [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)).

If you're really trying to put a scroll view and table view into the same view, then you'll need to look into `UIViewController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`, you can reasonably easily pull multiple view controllers (ideally with their proper classes, delegates and sources set in the storyboard) in and add their views to your outer wrapper view. I will say that I've done this and you can do cool things with it reasonably easily, but it usually isn't the cleanest way to do things.

Comment: thanks for the comment. but instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier does not help here since the viewcontroller for table view is not on story board. It does not allow me to assign viewcontroller to subviews as i can tell ( tableview is a subview here )  and hence the question on SO.

Comment: Why not have it on the storyboard? Storyboards make wiring things together easy. I come from a history of wanting to do a lot in code for control reasons, so I understand if that's your motivation, but if you're going to use storyboards at all it's easier just to use it fully.

Comment: does story board allow liking viewcontroller for subviews ? if yes, can you pls point me in the right dir. In my experience it does not allow to setup viewcontroller for subviews.

Comment: There are probably other ways of doing this, but one way of doing it for your example where you have one outer view with two inner views each with their own controller, would be to have have 3 view controllers on your storyboard. One for each of your sub views, fully wired with an identifier set for each. And one for the outer view. The outer view's controller would in its viewDidLoad call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier for each of the sub view controllers and then place their views where it wants them. It does add more 'clutter' to your storyboard but each piece can be very simple.

Comment: 1) when you say 'fully wired' - here problem is storyboard does not allow wiring vc to subview.  (2) as mentioned in the post i have already tried setting this up in viewDidLoad  but by then the subviews are already loaded and totally ignores any assigned vc in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: may be my question is not clear enough. but in short i am looking to have to have ability to wire up subviews in story board. rest will flow.