# Lifecycle of objects on storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I am looking for a document or link that explains the run time lifecycle of objects ( scenes ,segues,etc ) on xcode storyboard.

i.e right from unarchiving the storyboard archive and instantiating the objects/view/controllers.

In addition I am looking forward to acquire this info to resolve below query :

[how to set view controller programmatically for subview in storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384088/how-to-set-view-controller-programmatically-for-subview-in-storyboard/11384139#11384139)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some great articles for understanding life cycles.

- [The View Controller Life Cycle (*Displaying Your Views at Runtime*)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/DefiningYourSubclass.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW9)
- [The Life Cycle of a Segue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW13)

I'm not quite sure I understand your second question.

Answer (score 2):

More specifically, the [View Controller Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html) details how the initial view controller is configured at launch, and more generally how to use view controllers in storyboards.

For example, the first link tells you that the window.rootViewController is set by the time `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called, so you can configure it more there, and the second says how you can instantiate VCs through segues or directly in code loaded from your storyboard.